# Any way to capture the referring t.co link from Twitter?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, twitter, referer

I want to post multiple versions of the same link on Twitter but I want to capture them with unique identifiers when they hit my server.

Twitter partially devised a mechanism for this, for example if I post `www.example.com` into a twitter message, Twitter will automatically resolve it into a custom URL beginning with `t.co`via a 301 re-direct.

more information: [Twitter Link Wrapping](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/14d5474c13ed84aa?pli=1)

I want to capture this re-directed URL so I can have a unique identifier for similar links on Twitter.

Is there a way to do it? Or is there a better way to handle this problem?

(I'm looking for a solution in PHP/JS or if need be any possible way with any language)

**EDIT:** The link needs to be exactly the same in Twitter, can't have query parameters or hash on the link.

**EDIT2:** More investigation, the t.co link will remain the same if it's the same link url attributed to the same profile. For example, two links of `www.example.com` on the same twitter profile will yield the same t.co link, but the t.co link will be different if it's attributed to another profile. I guess this to mean even if there is a workaround for the above issue, there is still no way to differentiate exactly the same links on the same twitter profile server side.

**EDIT3 12/26/11** whats interesting too is that t.co differentiates between `http://` and `https` so you can in theory 'display' two of the same links on the same profile and they will look physically the same in Twitter but the t.co redirect link will be different. It will link to the http and https versions.

- Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is find out the tweet i.d of of a referring link that hits my server without resorting to URL params.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to to figure out which `t.co` link was used when your server was accessed? If so, why not just look at the referrer?

Comment: When you post to twitter, you receive tweet_id and you can query the tweet for this tweet_id. I believe they will return the modified link, and it's a manner of a regexp to get it and to match it to your link. Or I didn't understand the question. Anyway, interesting case, +1 for the question

Comment: I did look at the referrer with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `document.referrer` . It's just reading twitter.com. Looking through Fiddler, I see that it's being redirected twice - first to t.co then to scribe.twitter but none of this information is available. I would actually like to know if there is a way to not only get the t.co but ANY info programmaticly other then twitter.com because that would help the case a lot.

Comment: Darhazer: thanks I thought of that but I won't know the Tweet ID before hand. If I query for my link, I will get unique t.co links associated to tweet i.d's which is great but I still wont know which of those was the one that actually linked to the site at the time.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to place some kind of get parameter

page.php?referer=twitter

and check it like

```
<?php
if ($_GET['referer'] == "twitter")
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most reliable way to do this would be to share each link with some sort of an identifier of your own.

For example,

- www.domain.com/page-1?ref=1
- www.domain.com/page-1?ref=2
- etc.

You could easily implement tracking for the ref parameter in PHP or any other language you want.

Answer (score 0):

t.co doesn't carry the original referrer through. So you can't capture this after the redirection. You'll only see a t.co/foobar referrer.

Comment: actually you'll see twitter.com, not even t.co

Comment: I see both, but I guess the t.co/foobar referrer is from their verification bot.

Comment: very interesting, can you tell me the method you used to get the t.co/foobar referrer? And is it server side or client side?